# How to set datetime variable to null

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, datetime

I am having 2 textboxes and applied timepickers. Here I am leaving textboxes to null i.e not giving any date and sending to db as a fromdate and todate parameters.
in msql storedprocedure if Fromdate and todate are empty, one action is performed.inorder to do that task I have taken 2 variables

```
DateTime fromdate;
DateTime todate;
```

and declared as a Datetime in codebehind.

```
fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);
todate = Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);
```

When I am sending to db

```
fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);
todate = Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);
```

it is getting error.formate exception. Is it possible to apply null to datetime variables?

Comment: DateTime? Fromdate=null.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime? fromDate = null;
```

To answer the question in your comment, this is how you can return a `Nullable<DateTime>` (by creating an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)):

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(this string val)
    {
        DateTime temp;
        return DateTime.TryParse(val, out temp) ? (DateTime?) temp : null
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
DateTime? fromDate = txtfromdate.Text.ToNullableDateTime();
```

Comment: you mean dateTime? Fromdate=null; and dateTime? ToDate=null.......fromdate=Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);...todate =Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);...if i give like this is it accepts null??

Comment: Doesn't matter what the variable name is.

Comment: Note variables in C# are lowerCamelCase

Comment: hi..i am not able to convert to string to datetime?..fromdate=convert.todatetime(txt.text)..getting error here..how can i do this casting??

Comment: DateTime? fromdate=null;
        DateTime? todate=null;
        fromdate =Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);
        todate =Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);
        DataTable l_Assessment = new DataTable();
        //DataTable l_Assessment = objAssessmentFacade.GetAlltransactions(fromdate, todate, 0);
        l_Assessment = objAssessmentFacade.GetAlltransactions(fromdate, todate, _status);
        if (l_Assessment.Rows.Count >= 0)
        {
            gvtransactions.DataSource = l_Assessment;
            gvtransactions.DataBind();

        }

Comment: You can't do that, as `Convert.ToDateTime` returns a DateTime object. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DateTime? Fromdate=null
```

The "DateTime?" type  allow you to use it as null, but it is a value type struct.

Comment: hi..i am not able to convert to string to datetime?..fromdate=convert.todatetime(txt.text)..getting error here..how can i do this casting??

Comment: here is my content....  DateTime? fromdate=null;
        DateTime? todate=null;
        fromdate =Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);
        todate =Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);
        DataTable l_Assessment = new DataTable();
        //DataTable l_Assessment = objAssessmentFacade.GetAlltransactions(fromdate, todate, 0);
        l_Assessment = objAssessmentFacade.GetAlltransactions(fromdate, todate, _status);
        if (l_Assessment.Rows.Count >= 0)
        {
            gvtransactions.DataSource = l_Assessment;
            gvtransactions.DataBind();

        }